# Can't run old version of Xcode on macOS Sierra

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode4, xcode5, macos-sierra

I just tried to run old versions of Xcode on macOS Sierra.I've tried these versions:4.x,5.x,6.x. But I failed. All time I'm trying to launch old version it says that version of Xcode is incompatible with my macOS.How to fix this?Or I need to install old version of Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do is to change temporarily your system version.plist to a older Mac OS X like 10.6.8 is not wrong but you can't run old Xcode's officialy on macOS Sierra I could run Xcode 6 by just changing my version or dual boot Yosemite.

Sierra is only compatible with 7, 8, 9 those versions of Xcode can run on Sierra.

Look on stack overflow for a tutorial that illustrates how to change Mac OS version plist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should uninstall the old version and then install Xcode whose version is higher than 7, which may be useful.